# Unable to get pop to root working with NavigationStack in SwiftUI when pressing the tab bar icon

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mobile

I'm working on implementing a pop-to-root view for my tab bar views in SwiftUI. With my current code, I can print the `newValue` on every tap after the first. The code works as expected but does not reset the NavigationStack for the given tab. Is there something I'm missing here?

Here is the code, it's based on a video I found for more context. [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5yyZ8R2Dig)

```
import SwiftUI

struct TabViews: View {
    
    enum Tab {
        case friends, home, profile
    }
    
    @State private var activeTab: Tab = .home
    @State private var friendsStack: NavigationPath = .init()
    @State private var homeStack: NavigationPath = .init()
    @State private var profileStack: NavigationPath = .init()
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: tabSelection) {
            Group {
                NavigationStack(path: $friendsStack) {
                    Text("Friends")
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Image("FriendsTabIcon")
                }
                .tag(Tab.friends)
                
                NavigationStack(path: $homeStack) {
                    Text("Home")
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Image("HomeTabIcon")
                }
                .tag(Tab.home)
                
                NavigationStack(path: $profileStack) {
                    Text("Profile")
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Image("ProfileTabIcon")
                }
                .tag(Tab.profile)
            }
            .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .tabBar)
            .toolbarBackground(.brandBackground, for: .tabBar)
        }
    }
    
    var tabSelection: Binding<Tab> {
        return .init {
            return activeTab
        } set: { newValue in
            if newValue == activeTab {
                print(newValue)
                switch newValue {
                case .friends: friendsStack = .init()
                case .home: homeStack = .init()
                case .profile: profileStack = .init()
                }
            }
            activeTab = newValue
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    TabViews()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The comparison in `tabSelection` is backwards.

```
            if newValue == activeTab {
```

should be `!=`.